# tax_query does not work with pagination with custom query (both wp_query and query_posts())

Tags: pagination

I am using custom query for advance search with custom taxonomy .My pagination work well when does not use 'tax_query' .When I use 'tax_query' it does not show any post to next page and just show my "not found " notification. My code is here

```
/*
Template Name: search result
*/
 ?>

 <!-- prerequisite for search result show -->
 <?php 


// create array of all category list with empty 
$all_cat=array();  

$args = array(
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    );

$custom_terms = get_terms('ad_category',$args);   

 foreach($custom_terms as $key) {
        $all_cat[]=$key->slug;
    }

// end of foreach loop  
// end of taking all the arry of category list

// create array of all location list with empty 
$all_location=array();  

$args = array(
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    );

$custom_terms = get_terms('locations',$args);   

 foreach($custom_terms as $key) {
        $all_location[]=$key->slug;
    }

// end of foreach loop  
// end of taking all the arry of category list






 $get_location= $_POST['loc'];     // get the selected value for location 
 $v1=array();
 $get_category=$_POST['cat'];       // get the selected value for category


 // code for checking where any category select or not   
 if($get_category=="C")             // if no category selected then it return "C" as defauolt value    
    {
        // if defalut value then we need all the category in our search result
    }

else
    { 
        $all_cat=array( $get_category);   // if any category selected then just use this as search 
    }

// code for checking where any location select or not    
if($get_location=="L")             // if no location selected then it return "L" as defauolt value    
    {
            // default value means all location
    }

else
    {
        $all_location=array( $get_location);   // if any category selected then just use this as search      
    }



 wp_reset_query();  // reset wprdpress query
 ?>


 <!-- prerequisite for search result show -->

<?php get_header(); ?>




<section class="container bodychild"> <!--container-->
            <?php     
          $sidebar_data = array(
                    'umenu' => 1,
                    'heading'=> 'Tack',
                    'updata'=> 'för att du bidrar till en bättre värld!',
                    'downdata'=> 'Läs mer om Busenkelt.nu Klicka här',
                );
    include ('sidebar.php');
    ?>


        <section class="content_area">
            <div class="heap">
                <h1>Testing Pagination</h1>
                <div class="ask-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon-info.png">
                </div>
                <img class="rimg" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon/icon-heart.png">
             </div>
             <hr class="uhr">

             <?php
             if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
                  ?>
            <div class="ad-con">   
                  <?php
                global $current_user;
                get_currentuserinfo();
            ?>
            <?php  $p = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  ?>
                <?php 
                global $query_string;
                $args = wp_parse_args($query_string);
                $post_pre_page=5;
                $offset = ( $p - 1 ) * $post_pre_page;

                $args = array(  'post_type' => 'advertise', 
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page'    => $post_pre_page,


                                // 'tax_query' => array(        
                                //         array(
                                //                 'taxonomy' => 'ad_category',                
                                //                 'field' => 'slug', 
                                //                 'terms' => $all_cat,
                                //                 'operator' => 'IN'  
                                //             )

                                // ),
                                'offset'=> $offset,
                                'orderby'=>'date',
                                'order'=>'DESC',
                                'paged'=>$p,

                        );
                $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
                query_posts($args);
                global $wp_query;
                // Store it for safekeeping
                $temp_wp_query = $wp_query;
                // Now blank it out
                $wp_query = null;
                // Now populate it with your custom query
                $wp_query = $loop;


                ?>
                <div class="prevnext">
                    <p>
                        <span class="left">
                            <?php echo 'Page '. $p . ' of ' .$loop-> max_num_pages; ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>

</div>
<hr class="uhr">
                 <?php   if ( have_posts() ) {?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="ind-ad" id="<?php echo 'ad-'.get_the_ID();?>">
                <div class="show-ads-con">
                    <div class="show-ads-sub1">
                        <div class="show-ads1">
                          <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image1', true ) ) { ?>
                                <?php  $imager = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image1', true ) ;?>
                                <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($imager); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                          <?php  } 
                                 else {
                                        echo "no image 1";
                                 } 
                          ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="show-ads-sub2">
                        <div class="show-ads2">
                           <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image2', true ) ) { ?>
                                <?php  $imager = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image2', true ) ;?>
                                <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($imager); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                          <?php  } 
                                 else {
                                        echo "no image 2";
                                 } 
                          ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-ads3">
                          <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image3', true ) ) { ?>
                                <?php  $imager = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image3', true ) ;?>
                                <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($imager); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                          <?php  } 
                                 else {
                                        echo "no image 3";
                                 } 
                          ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="show-ads4">
                          <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image4', true ) ) { ?>
                                <?php  $imager = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'add_image4', true ) ;?>
                                <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($imager); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                          <?php  } 
                                 else {
                                        echo "no image 4";
                                 } 
                          ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="man-ad-info">
                         <h3> Post id :  <?php the_ID(); ?></h3>
                         <h3> Title :  <?php the_title() ?></h3>
                         <h3> Author Name :   <?php the_author(); ?> </h3>
                         <h3> Author Id :   <?php the_author_meta('ID')?> </h3>
                         <p> Gilltig till:   </p>
                         <div class="bllab">
                            <label>
                                <select>
                                   <option>
                                        <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'val-year', true ) ) { ?>
                                        <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'val-year', true ) ;  ?>  
                                        <?php } 
                                              else {
                                                echo "no data";
                                              } 
                                        ?>
                                   </option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <select>
                                   <option>
                                        <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'val-month', true ) ) { ?>
                                        <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'val-month', true ) ;  ?>  
                                        <?php } 
                                              else {
                                                echo "no data";
                                              } 
                                        ?>
                                   </option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <select>
                                   <option>
                                        <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'val-day', true ) ) { ?>
                                        <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'val-day', true ) ;  ?>  
                                        <?php } 
                                              else {
                                                echo "no data";
                                              } 
                                        ?>
                                   </option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                         </div>
                        <p class="man-status"> Status:   </p>
                        <div class="btn-container">
                            <div class="btn-on-left">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="btn-left-a clico"></div>
                                    <div class="btn-right-a"> Ta bort</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                        <hr class="uhr">
                </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <?php
                        // $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                        // echo paginate_links( array(
                        //     'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        //     'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        //     'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        //     'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
                        //     'prev_text'    => __('&laquo; Previous'),
                        //     'next_text'    => __('Next &raquo;')
                        //     ));
                        ?>
                        <ul class="pagination">

  <li id="previous-posts">

    <?php previous_posts_link( '<< Previous Posts', $loop->max_num_pages ); ?>

  </li>

  <li id="next-posts">

    <?php next_posts_link( 'Next Posts >>', $loop->max_num_pages ); ?>

  </li>

</ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        } 
                        else {
                            echo '<div class="user-nli"> no sparade ad found for this author. </div>';
                            echo '<hr class="uhr">';
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        $wp_query = $temp_wp_query;
                    ?>
           </div>
           <?php
            } 
            else {
                echo '<div class="user-nli"> If registered User? go to <a href="'.get_site_url().'"> Home page </a>  and Log in Or <a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Registrering' ) ,false)).'">Register</a> as a User. </div>';
                echo '<hr class="uhr">';
            }
           ?>

<div class="content_button_left">
    <a href="<?php echo  home_url(); ?>">
        <input class="gostep1" type="button" value="Next Stage"> 
    </a>
</div> 


        </section>


    <div class="clear"></div>
</section><!-- end container -->
<?php require_once('check.php');?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: of your query do not return results then there is no reason to paginate.

Comment: You're not setting up `$all_cat`

Comment: actually it show result only on first page but when I click to next page it's show no post( actually does not found any post to show) . I setting up $call_cat

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the `tax_query`, but rather the **`offset`**. [Offset and pagination do not play nicely together](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters):

> offset (int) - number of post to displace or pass over. Warning: Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter **and breaks pagination**

The Codex has a [somewhat involved workaround](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination).

Comment: I use offset with remove just 'tag_query' from my code and it's work fine . Here is my complete code:

Comment: I solve my problem .Actually it was not pagination problem.I take some value using post method from previous page and when I clicked on next page( or may be other page) all post data lost . So ,I use session variable to store my required value.Thanks to all .